# How can I make 3 rows and 3 columns so that when div is expanded the column just moves down (pic in the body)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

Is it possible to use flex-box and javascript or some other technique to create a website design as show below.

In the first picture there is 3 rows and 3 columns that are aligned as a 3x3 grid

In the second picture there is a hover over effect on one of the pictures. I don't know how to achieve this effect. And would love some advices on this.

Thank you in advance.

[Divs before hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceKHa.png)

[divs after hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkvHf.png)

```
**Edited**:
```

Yes I'll only show text when it is hovered over. I have tried to add flex-box to the divs. But it giver 4 columns when hovered.

```
.palvelut-container {
        height: 1000px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content:space-between;
        flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-palvelu{
    flex: 1 1 30%;
}
```

I have also tried adding height to container on hover, but it didn't work

```
   .palvelut-container:hover {
         Height: 1700px;
    }
```

Comment: do you want to display text on the image when you hover over the image??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: so you would just like to achieve the effect you have in the "div after hover" image?  I take it you do not care if the container expands to fit the text.

Comment: Yes the container can expand. So the problem is that I have a container under which I have 9 divs. In each div the user only sees the title before he hovers over the div and then the div shows the content underneath the div. I have already coded the part that divs show only the title in the beginning and after hover it shows the whole content.

Comment: So if you do not want the area to expand and the content in the hovered area to overlap the image under it or you want the entire row to expand use the grid answer if you want the area to expand and push the image below it down then use the flexbox answer but be sure your content behind the image will always be bigger than the image or add a min height to the container to avoid hover bounce. If I had to guess I would say you will go the flexbox route  Let me know if you have any questions comments or concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you KJEK-Code. That was the answer to my question. I had to tweak a little bit the backend code to get it work. I posted the code I used below, if someone is having similar problems.

Thank you all for the answers. I had struggled with this a while!

Here's the css.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.palvelut-container {
    flex: 33.3%;
    max-width: 33.3%;
}
```

Here's the back end I used for wordpress

```
<div class="wrapper container">
    <div class="palvelut-container">    


        <?php
        //Columns must be a factor of 12 (1,2,3,4,6,12)


            $args = array('parent' => 22, 'hide_empty' => false); // <!-- change to false to also display empty ones);
            $categories = get_categories( $args );

            $numOfCols = 3;
            $rowCount = 1;



            $numberOfPosts = count($categories);
            $bootstrapColWidth = ceil($numberOfPosts/$numOfCols);



            foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
                <div class="flex-palvelu">
                    <div class="thumbnail palvelut-ylataso" style="min-height: 300px;
                                                                    background: url(<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($category->term_id); ?>);
                                                                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                                                    background-size: cover;">
                       <?php
                            echo '<a class="ylataso-palvelulinkki" href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "Katso kaikki %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . '<h3 class="palvelu-otsikko">' . $category->name.' </h3> ';

                            ?>
                             <span class="palvelut-alataso">
                               <?php
                              $args1 = array (
                                'post_type' => 'hoito',
                                'category_name' => $category->name
                              );

                              $new_cpt_query = new WP_Query($args1);
                                while( $new_cpt_query->have_posts() ) : $new_cpt_query->the_post();

                                ?>
                                <span class="palvelut-linkki"">
                                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                </span>


                                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
                            </span> 
                            </a>
                    </div> 
                </div>  
                    <?php

                        if ($rowCount == $bootstrapColWidth && $numberOfPosts > 1) {
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "<div class='palvelut-container'> ";
                            $rowCount = 1;
                            $numberOfPosts--;
                        } else {
                            $rowCount++;
                            $numberOfPosts--;
                        }
            }
            ?>

    </div>      

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Juho Pouttu welcome to stack overflow.
so this is about the best answer I can give you at this point.  You would need to use grid in order to keep the size of the container stable when you hide the image as you hover over. Once you have done that you can then show the text under it.  I used a list just for easy coding but it can be whatever you want it to be.. IE a div with paragraph text in it or whatever.  now for the expansion, the container of whatever you are showing would need to be position absolute so that it can break outside of the container and it will need a background so it can go over the other images. If you want the whole row to expand just remove position absolute if that better suits your wants/needs. hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

     .wrapper-div {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
     } 
    
    .container-div {
        padding: 1rem;
    }

    .container-div:hover > img {
        display: none;
    }

    .container-div:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }

     img {
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
     }

     ul {
        list-style: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 1rem;
        display: none;
     }

     li {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
     }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-div">
            <div class="container-div">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container-div">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container-div">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container-div">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container-div">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container-div">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container-div">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container-div">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container-div">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                    <li>Example of text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

ok, second answer would be with flexbox which seems like it would suit your needs a bit better... same concept however if your content that you display after the hover effect is to short you will experience issues with hover bounce

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
    }

    .column {
        flex: 33.33%;
        max-width: 33.33%;
    }
    .column-divider {
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    .column-divider:hover > img {
        display: none;
    }

    .column-divider:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: none;
    }
    li {
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="column-divider">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="placeholder">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="column-divider">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="placeholder">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="column-divider">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="placeholder">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="column-divider">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="placeholder">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="column-divider">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="placeholder">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="column-divider">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="placeholder">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="column-divider">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="placeholder">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="column-divider">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="placeholder">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="column-divider">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360" alt="placeholder">
                <ul>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                    <li>Example text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ill keep working on this because I don't feel like this is the best answer